# React Native auto fill and suggestions for email and password inputs

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Native 0.63.4 and my goal is to have auto fill working both on Android and iOS:

- get email suggestions (for example, when filling the email input on sign up and when logging in for the first time)
- get asked to save the password after successfully logged in
- get the saved credentials when logging in again

Here's the component I am using for the inputs:

```
const InputField: React.FC<Props> = ({
  placeholder,
  onTextChange,
  keyboardType = "default",
  securedTextEntry,
  isMissing,
  textContentType = "none",
  autoCompleteType = "off"
}) => {

  const [thisSecureTextEntry, setThisSecureTextEntry] = useState(false);

  const isAutoCapitalizeDisabled =
    keyboardType === 'email-address' || 'password' ? 'none' : 'sentences';

  const importantForAutofill = autoCompleteType ? 'yes' : 'no';
  

  const updateThisSecureTextEntry = (value: boolean) => {
    if(securedTextEntry) {
      setThisSecureTextEntry(value);
    }
  }

  return (
    Platform.OS === 'ios' ?
        <TextInput
          style={styles.text}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          placeholderTextColor={isMissing ? ERROR_TEXT : PLACEHOLDER_GRAY}
          onChangeText={onTextChange}
          onFocus={() => updateThisSecureTextEntry(true)}
          onBlur={() => updateThisSecureTextEntry(true)}
          secureTextEntry={thisSecureTextEntry}
          keyboardType={keyboardType}
          autoCapitalize={isAutoCapitalizeDisabled}
          
          textContentType={textContentType}
        /> : 
        <TextInput
          style={styles.text}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          placeholderTextColor={isMissing ? ERROR_TEXT : PLACEHOLDER_GRAY}
          onChangeText={onTextChange}
          onFocus={() => updateThisSecureTextEntry(true)}
          onBlur={() => updateThisSecureTextEntry(true)}
          secureTextEntry={thisSecureTextEntry}
          keyboardType={keyboardType}
          autoCapitalize={isAutoCapitalizeDisabled}
          
          autoCompleteType={autoCompleteType}
          importantForAutofill={importantForAutofill}
        />
  );
};

export default InputField;
```

And here's how I use it for login:

```
<InputField
          placeholder={translations.EMAIL}
          onTextChange={setEmail}
          keyboardType={'email-address'}
          autoCompleteType={'username'}
          textContentType={'username'}
        />
        <InputField
          placeholder={translations.PASSWORD}
          onTextChange={setPassword}
          securedTextEntry={true}
          autoCompleteType={'password'}
          textContentType={'password'}
        />
```

- I had to maintain the state of `secureTextEntry` and change the value `onFocus` and `onBlur` to correctly get email suggestions on iOS ([link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27586#issuecomment-580739397))

**iOS problem**:
If I set `textContentType` as `username`, I get asked to save the password on iOS but I don't get email suggestions the first time I am filling the login. If I set it to `emailAddress`, I get the suggestions but then I am not asked to save the password.

**Android problem**:
Even with `autoCompleteType` and `importantForAutofill` set, I am never asked to save the password.

I tried to add a permission to AndroidManifest.xml `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_AUTOFILL_SERVICE" />` but it made no difference.

I have auto fill enabled on the settings of the two devices (android and ios) that I am using.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: hello. how did you solved this please. ?